# How to change color and weight of text in VS2010 Text Adornment Extension?

Tags: wpf, vs-extensibility

In my TextAdornment1 class, I have the following defined:

```
  ' <summary>'
  ' On layout change add the adornment to any reformatted lines'
  ' </summary>'
  Private Sub OnLayoutChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TextViewLayoutChangedEventArgs) Handles _view.LayoutChanged
    For Each line In e.NewOrReformattedLines
      Me.CreateVisuals(line)
    Next line
  End Sub
```

An instance of `ITextViewLine` gets passed to my `CreateVisuals` method. How do I change the color of the text on that particular line, and how do I make it bold? I see plenty of examples of drawing images to highlight text, but nothing so far that changes the formatting of the actual text. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done via the adornments (AFAIK, they only add elements to the window, not alter existing ones).

I recommend you look into the "Editor Classifiers" which will allow you to alter the formatting of text (the VS SDK includes a good project template for classifiers).